# Meta analysis of one-armed observational studies with varying follow up (time)?

Tags: r, meta-analysis, observational-study

I am about to start a meta analysis investigating the retention of different dental fissure sealers. Data extracted from the studies are:

1. (number of teeth completely sealed at the end of study)
2. (total number of teeth initially sealed at the beginning of study)

Studies are divided according to material investigated, and they all vary on time length (some studies count the teeth after 2 years, some after 5, and so on.) I am planning on using R. Right now I'm thinking about survival curves?

Each row holds the name of study, material investigated, follow up (when they counted teeth at end of study, either 2 or 3 or 4 years for example), number of teeth sealed at that time, and total number of teeth sealed at start. I am not really sure what I can do with this data, so anything is much appreciated.

Comment: I think we need more detail here as, on the face of it, you do not have the information you would need to generate a survival curve from each study. Can you expand your question with more information?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is all the information I have to conduct this meta-analysis, I am not sure what I can do with it. All I have is the number of teeth sealed (from total initially sealed) after (2 years or 3 years or 5 years,... depending on study) for different materials ( also depending on study). I am open to all suggestions.

Comment: Does https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241960/meta-analysis-of-proportions help you?

Comment: Actually yes! thanks! one question though, Study weights in the forest plot depend not only on sample size but follow up time too? if not, is there a way I can do that?

Comment: You could enter follow-up time as a moderator in a meta-regression to see its effect. That would also be appropriate if you wanted just to adjust for it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make the comments into a proper answer.

Meta-analysing a single proportion from each study is perfectly possible and more details can be found in [this Q&A}([Meta-analysis of proportions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241960/meta-analysis-of-proportions)).

In the specific case here where there is variable follow-up between studies the value of that can be entered as a moderator in a meta-regression. The only slight drawback is that there is no overall summary in a meta-regression and you can only generate an estimate for a specific illustrative follow-up time or times.