# Type of studies reviewed in meta-analysis of proportion

Tags: meta-analysis, proportion

What types of studies are reviewed for meta-analysis of proportions? For example can I included case-control studies and collect data of number of events from the total cases?

Comment: What specifically is the objective of your meta-analysis?

Comment: thank you for replying, basically its To study the proportion of women who developed breast cancer and their first age of pregnancy was in the period of 20-35 years.

Comment: You mean you want to pool the prevalence of breast ca through meta-analysis?

Comment: yes , the prevalence of breast cancer among women whom first age of pregnancy is between 20 and 35 years . I want to do a meta- analysis in order to pool the proportions from case-control and cohort studies from different countries.

Answer (score 1):

From your reply to the comment above, your plan is to estimate the prevalence of a given health condition (specifically, breast ca) in a certain population group. If that is the case, studies estimating prevalence are cross-sectional studies. Therefore, the studies you need to include need to be cross-sectional ones. Case-control studies are not designed to estimate prevalence of a given health outcome, but rather to estimate risk factors. In fact, prevalence of a risk factor may be estimated separately for cases and controls in case-control studies but that doesn’t seem to be your objective.

For your question

> “for example can I included case-control studies and collect data of number of events from the total cases?”,

my answer is “no” because in case-control studies, how many cases (persons with a disease) will be included into your study is decided by the design of your study – that is, if you decide to have a case-control study with a case-to-control ratio of `1:1`, by default you will have a prevalence of `50%` which is not representative of the prevalence of the disease in the reference population.

Cohort studies are meant primarily to estimate incidence (not prevalence) and risk factors. Hence, you may consider cohort studies if you also have an interest in incidence and/or risk factors.

Though not directly related to your question, looking at a previous post on [meta-analysis of proportions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241960/meta-analysis-of-proportions) here on CV could be useful.

Comment: thank you for replying, so that means if I have case-control and cohort studies it would be better to extract OR and RR and do a pooled OR and RR meta-analysis ?

Comment: Yes, if you plan to pool the effect sizes of risk factors.